# Why does adding an element to a PDF file using iTextSharp result in "An error exists on this page"

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I am new to iTextSharp. I am using iTextSharp version 4.1.6.0 to generate PDF reports and I am encountering an error message when reading the file in Adobe Acrobat. The error is "An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem".

The error occurs at a point where 5 boxes (with text inside) are being added, from left to right. The first 4 are added without any error. If I add the final box to the document, the error occurs.

The 5 boxes are added with the below code:

```
    Dim objDirectContent As PdfContentByte = pdfW.DirectContent
```

...

```
    paragraph = New Paragraph(New Chunk("Text content 1.",
                                        New Font(bodyFont, FontSize, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)))
    paragraph.Leading = DefaultLeading
    columnText = New ColumnText(objDirectContent)
    columnText.AddElement(paragraph)
    DrawTextBox(objDirectContent, columnText, 0.5, yLine - contentHeight, 0.5 + width * (1 / 5), yLine, New iTextSharp.text.Color(255, 255, 255))
    paragraph = New Paragraph(New Chunk("Text content 2.",
                                        New Font(bodyFont, FontSize, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)))
    paragraph.Leading = DefaultLeading
    columnText = New ColumnText(objDirectContent)
    columnText.AddElement(paragraph)
    DrawTextBox(objDirectContent, columnText, 0.5 + width * (1 / 5), yLine - contentHeight, 0.5 + width * (2 / 5), yLine, New iTextSharp.text.Color(255, 255, 255))
    paragraph = New Paragraph(New Chunk("Text content 3.",
                                        New Font(bodyFont, FontSize, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)))
    paragraph.Leading = DefaultLeading
    columnText = New ColumnText(objDirectContent)
    columnText.AddElement(paragraph)
    DrawTextBox(objDirectContent, columnText, 0.5 + width * (2 / 5), yLine - contentHeight, 0.5 + width * (3 / 5), yLine, New iTextSharp.text.Color(255, 255, 255))
    paragraph = New Paragraph(New Chunk("Text content 4.",
                                        New Font(bodyFont, FontSize, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)))
    paragraph.Leading = DefaultLeading
    columnText = New ColumnText(objDirectContent)
    columnText.AddElement(paragraph)
    DrawTextBox(objDirectContent, columnText, 0.5 + width * (3 / 5), yLine - contentHeight, 0.5 + width * (4 / 5), yLine, New iTextSharp.text.Color(255, 255, 255))
    paragraph = New Paragraph(New Chunk("Text content 5.",
                                        New Font(bodyFont, FontSize, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)))

    paragraph.Leading = DefaultLeading
    columnText = New ColumnText(objDirectContent)
    columnText.AddElement(paragraph)

    ' BUG IS HERE!
    DrawTextBox(objDirectContent, columnText, 0.5 + width * (4 / 5), yLine - contentHeight, 0.5 + width, yLine, New iTextSharp.text.Color(255, 255, 255))
```

DrawTextBox:

```
Private Function DrawTextBox(ByRef objDirectContent As PdfContentByte, ByRef columnText As ColumnText,
            ByVal sngX1 As Single, ByVal sngY1 As Single, ByVal sngX2 As Single, ByVal sngY2 As Single,
            ByVal objFillColour As iTextSharp.text.Color) As Single

    Dim objStrokeColour As Color = New iTextSharp.text.Color(0, 0, 0)
    Dim cellPadding As Single = 0.05


    columnText.SetSimpleColumn((sngX1 + cellPadding) * PPI, (sngY1 + cellPadding) * PPI, (sngX2 - cellPadding) * PPI, (sngY2 - cellPadding) * PPI, DefaultLeading, PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT)
    DrawBox(objDirectContent, sngX1, sngY1, sngX2, sngY2, objStrokeColour, objFillColour)

    columnText.Go()

    Dim yLine As Single = sngY1
    Return yLine

End Function
```

DrawBox:

```
Private Sub DrawBox(ByRef objDirectContent As PdfContentByte, _
            ByVal sngX1 As Single, ByVal sngY1 As Single, ByVal sngX2 As Single, ByVal sngY2 As Single, _
            ByVal objStrokeColour As iTextSharp.text.Color, ByVal objFillColour As iTextSharp.text.Color)


    objDirectContent.SetLineWidth(1.0)
    objDirectContent.SetColorStroke(objStrokeColour)
    objDirectContent.SetColorFill(objFillColour)

    objDirectContent.Rectangle(sngX1 * PPI, sngY1 * PPI, (sngX2 - sngX1) * PPI, (sngY2 - sngY1) * PPI)
    If objFillColour.Equals(New iTextSharp.text.Color(255, 255, 255)) Then
        objDirectContent.ClosePathStroke()
    Else
        objDirectContent.ClosePathFillStroke()
    End If
End Sub
```

This code was written by an ex-colleague so I might not be able to answer all 'why are you doing it like this' type questions, however I would appreciate any helpful comments if my use of iText is not appropriate.

If anyone has any ideas on what may be causing this error, or how to debug it, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Try creating a brand new project and putting only the above code in and see what happens

Comment: Also: upgrade to a more recent version of iTextSharp. More tests have been added in more recent versions. These tests tell you what you're doing wrong.